# PHP how to Remove non-language Characters from a String?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

how can i to remove all characters non-language ?

i want to remove characters like this below, and all other of not language characters:

```

```

i using this:

```
preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9A-Z\-\'\|\!\.\?\:\)\(\;\*\"]/u", " ", $text );
```

this is good for english,
i need to approve all language characters, like Russian,arabic,hebrew,japan...

Are there any string functions I can use to leave all language characters?

thanks

Comment: What you have there are code points in the private use area. By "non-language characters", do you mean characters that are not typically used, like private use area code points? Or any symbols, like "☃"? What about "→"? That's useful in written text.

Comment: yes, i want to remove all symbols and other are not typically used in regular keyboard, like A-Z i'm using, but for all languages

Comment: How far do you want to go for "text"? There are giant sections for lots of typography related things, which is arguably language related. What's the primary goal/reason for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No regex will be perfect for what you want - language and writing are just too complex for this. But an approximation could be

```
preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{M}\p{Z}\p{N}\p{P}]/u', ' ', $text);
```

This will replace anything by a space that's not a Unicode character with one of the properties “letter”, “mark”, “separator”, “number” or “punctuation”.

Answer (score 1):

Tim Pietzcker's answer not working in my case.

This works.

```
$after = preg_replace('/[^\w\s]+/u','' , $before);
```

Comment: worked for me thanks. awesome